# pytest dynamically parametrized test

Tags: python, pytest

I have created a 'dynamic' list of parameters which I pass to parametrize.

```
OPTIONS = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def get_unique_pairs():
    unique_list = []
    for first in OPTIONS:
        for second OPTIONS:
            if first == second:
                continue
            unique_list.append({'first':first, 'second':second))
    return unique_list

def some_func()
    unique_pairs = get_unique_pairs()
    result = []
    for pair in unique_pair:
        if test(pair):
           continue
        else:
           result.append(pair)
    return pair

@pytest.mark.parametrize('param', some_fnc())
def test_fnc(param):
    first = param['first']
    second = param['second']
```

The input I wish to pass to `test_fnc` is `[('a','b'),('a','c')...('c','b')]` where the first and second elements are never the same. There is some additional logic I am using to further remove specific pairs.

When I run the test I get the output:

```
::test_fnc[param0] PASSED
::test_fnc[param1] PASSED
::test_fnc[param2] PASSED
```

I have two issues:

1. I'm not entirely sure how to describe what I am doing to find further documentation / help.
2. I would like more descriptive output (i.e. not `param0`), and I'd like to continue using dictionaries to pass data to the test.

Comment: I'm under the impression that your `get_unique_pairs` can be replaced by `list(itertools.combinations(OPTIONS, 2))`. Also, take a look at generator functions and generator expressions, they can make your code more concise and idiomatic.

Comment: Thats pretty cool - thanks. I'll have a play, I'd like it to generate ['c', 'a'] - inverting the combinations.

Comment: Combinatoric iterators are: product, permutations, combinations and combinations_with_replacement. The `combinations(p, r)` iterator returns r-length tuples in sorted order, no repeated elements. Product is equivalent to your nested for loop: `[(a, b) for a, b in product(OPTIONS, OPTIONS) if a != b]`

Comment: `itertools.permutations(OPTIONS, 2)` is a much cleaner way of writing what I was doing!

Comment: Everyday you learn a new thing. Welcome to StackOverflow! Python community here is awesome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
import pytest
import itertools


OPTIONS = ['a', 'b', 'c']

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'param',
    itertools.permutations(OPTIONS, 2),
    ids=lambda pair: "first={}, second={}".format(*pair)
)
def test_fn(param):
    first, second = param
    assert first != second
```

Result:

```
> pytest --verbose 
================================ test session starts =================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.6.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /usr/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/paulos/work/lixo/tests, inifile:
collected 6 items

test_foo.py::test_fn[first=a, second=b] PASSED                                     [ 16%]
test_foo.py::test_fn[first=a, second=c] PASSED                                     [ 33%]
test_foo.py::test_fn[first=b, second=a] PASSED                                     [ 50%]
test_foo.py::test_fn[first=b, second=c] PASSED                                     [ 66%]
test_foo.py::test_fn[first=c, second=a] PASSED                                     [ 83%]
test_foo.py::test_fn[first=c, second=b] PASSED                                     [100%]

================================ 6 passed in 0.03 seconds ================================
```

[update]

> I think this answer is the solution I will use. Every day is a school day! (Out of curiosity is there a way I could be the 'param' into something like 'first, second' so to have test_foo(param) be test_foo(first, second). I'm not sure that actually helps anything... but I am curious – F. Elliot

If you don't mind a `test_fn[a-b]` instead of  `test_fn[a, b]`:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'first,second',
    itertools.permutations(OPTIONS, 2),
)
def test_fn(first, second):
    assert first != second
```

In practice we don't really run tests with `--verbose` anyway, so most of the time the output will be just a dot for each test.

Comment: I think this answer is the solution I will use. Every day is a school day! (Out of curiosity is there a way I could be the 'param' into something like 'first, second' so to have test_foo(param) be test_foo(first, second). I'm not sure that actually helps anything... but I am curious

Answer (score 5):

1. As [Paulo Scardine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444036/paulo-scardine) mentioned in the comment, don't reinvent the wheel, use `itertools.combinations`.
2. You are looking for the [`ids` argument in `parametrize` hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids). It's either list of names for each argument, or a function that accepts the argument and returns a string - `repr` is a simple solution for builtin types.

Combined example:

```
import itertools
import pytest


opts = ['a', 'b', 'c']


@pytest.mark.parametrize('param', itertools.combinations(opts, 2), ids=repr)
def test_fn(param):
    first = param[0]
    second = param[1]
    assert first != second
```

Comment: I found this and Paulos post useful - thank you for the link also, I didnt realise ids could be a function. (I spent some time trying seeing if I could separate param out by using a dict, but I guess I'll just kick my obsession with dictionaries for now!)

Comment: You can have dicts if you want - just build them from `itertools.combinations(opts, 2)`, e.g. `[{'first': first, 'second': second} for first, second in itertools.combinations(opts, 2)]`.

Comment: How would I changed 'ids'? I feel like the keys of the dictionary are being passed in

Comment: You can continue using `repr`, or write a custom format function, for example `def dump(param): return ', '.join('{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in param.items())` and use it with `ids=dump`. This will give you test names like `test_fn[first=a, second=b]`.